# 2,5 GB free storage is not enough to install aps on Huawei P7 mini, Android 4.4.2

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage, huawei

I have Huawei P7 mini with Android 4.4.2.
I'm generally installing apps on SD card which is almost completely free.
I have, however, over 2,5 GB free internal storage.
But Google Play don't let me install or update apps, claiming that I have 'not enough internal storage'. Apps can't be updated from google play in browser as well. 
Apparently, you can't install or update apps until you have at least 3GB free internal storage(?!?) What can I do about that? Factory reset of the phone is simply not an option (not all apps allow to be backuped).

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a bug. 
Try going into settings, apps,  selecting GooglePlay app, force closing and clearing the data and cache.
If necessary do the same thing with GooglePlayServices.

This may solve or problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing caches to make some free space on internal storage. One common app you can find on Play Store is "Clear App Cache". I faced the same issue when I used Xperia C device. It had limited storage and I need to clean cache to update or install a new app from Play Store.

Comment: Link for the app and brief description about it. Also are you affiliated to the product?